# ignore python cache in Unison: ignore Path */__pycache__

Tags: regex, unison

Is

```
ignore Path */__pycache__
```

the correct approach to ignore all python cache files from being synced with Unison?

[image]

I do so by adding `Path */__pycache__` in the graphical user interface.

I know very little about regular expressions. I tried to do this based on [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#pathspec](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#pathspec)
but I would be happy if someone could confirm if this will actually lead to the desired effect or if there is a better solution?

PS: Unison still tries to synchronize my pycache files and folders :(
How can I stop it from doing so?

Comment: Try `Path {.*,*}__pycache__` without that slash. Also, note that `Path` isn't expecting a regex pattern but instead a standard "globbing" pattern.

Comment: I know very little about regex and nothing about gobbing

Comment: "Globbing." But more importantly did `Path {.*,*}__pycache__` work?

Comment: no, some of the __ pycache__ flies are still listed by Unison

Answer (score 0):

This just worked for me (on Unison v2.51.3.70):

```
Name {__pycache__}
```